# How come Chrome/Edge allow entering domains that have invalid domain SSL certificates?

Tags: google-chrome, redirection, microsoft-edge, ssl-certificate

If you browse to biji.co/ads.txt manually via Chrome/Edge it works. In Firefox though it fails:
[image: Firefox fails]

> Websites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for `biji.co`. The certificate is only valid for `www.biji.co`.
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN
>
> Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server’s certificate.
>
> HTTP Strict Transport Security: false
>
> HTTP Public Key Pinning: false

When checking its headers through online header checkers they get errors too confirming the webpage is supposed to be inaccessible.

http://www.rexswain.com/cgi-bin/httpview.pl

[image: SSL issue]

https://network-tools.com/http-headers/

[image: SSL issue]

So how come Chrome/Edge don't alert about it and just accept this broken certificate?

Comment: Safari warns me about both links.  I don’t understand your question

Comment: I've added a clarification that Chrome/Edge let you enter the link while other browsers don't. So the question is why do Chrome/Edge do so?

Comment: Chrome and Edge gives me a notification that the certificate isn’t valid. Are you sure you haven’t previously trusted the certificate in the past?  The certificate generated a warning on every browser I have tried

Comment: Pretty sure, it doesn't exist in the list of Chrome's certificates: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IDC9.png - plus I used InCognito, different profile and Guest mode.

Comment: Chrome and Edge use the certificate store of the OS. Firefox doesn’t.